# document.ready not executing on every load

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache

I have a strange problem. I have a jQuery document.ready function executing some script on the page. When I was testing it through opening the file with firefox/opera it worked. When I uploaded it to the server (I tried both my home apache and my shared hosting) it only works once in 10 loads maybe.

What could be the problem?

Thanks beforehand

**Edit:**

Here is the code. It configures the correct size of side panels according to central panel.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            // Get natural heights
            var cHeight = $("#content").height();   
            var nHeight = $("#left").height() - $("#footer").height() - $("#header").height() - 10; 

            // Assign maximum height to all columns
            $("#leftcontent").height(nHeight);
            $("#rightcontent").height(nHeight);
            $("#left").height(cHeight);
            $("#right").height(cHeight);
         });            
    </script>
```

Comment: You have Firebug? Is it reporting any JS errors when you load the page?

Comment: It may have something to do with caching. Disable caching on your browser, or delete the cache before each load to see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have no JS syntax errors first (firebug or simply the error console).

If not have you considered just putting a simple alert in the ready function.  If that still fails you know its something to do with the JQuery library itself (unlikely).

If you consistently get alerts you know its a problem with your own code. Further help with that will require sight of your code.

Comment: Firebug reports no problems in code, but on server code just does not execute - if I set a breakpoint it never fires. It DOES fire when I do it outside the server. I'll post the code in second comment.

Comment: I mean that it works when I just move to the folder and open with mozzila. When I put it into www folder of Apache server and open it through localhost - it stops working.

Comment: Anyhow - it works pretty stable after I moved css links above js links in <head>. I have no idea why it works now :(